# Show that a given function of $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ is a probability density function

Tags: probability

Let $\phi$ and $\Phi$ be the standard normal density and distribution functions.

Show that $\Phi(\lambda x) = 1 - \Phi(-\lambda x)$ and that $f(x) = 2\phi(x)\Phi(\lambda x)$ is a probability density function.

---

My thoughts:  the first part is true by symmetry around 0.  I tried to show this using the definition of $\phi$ and integral $\Phi$ but struggled.  The second part, I'm not sure what is meant by show it is a PDF.  Isn't the only criterion that $\int f(x) = 1$?  I tried using the expression from the first part with the definition/integrals again, but couldn't seem to get the trick involved.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty (f(x)+f(-x))\,dx $$

(The criterion for being a PDF is (a) that the function is nonnegative, and (b) that its integral is 1).